# JProgressBar working according to application load in swing

Tags: java, swing, jprogressbar

I want to develop small project for file copy application in java swing.
I want to show progress bar for that, means how much percent data is been copy..
so can any body tell me idea how to develop it

Comment: You need to show your attempt first

Comment: Please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: You could take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394898/how-create-progress-bar-while-file-transfering/13395076#13395076) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574461/need-to-have-jprogress-bar-to-measure-progress-when-copying-directories-and-file/13574755#13574755) for some ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure thing. Here is an idea: When you copy files use `InputStream` and read a standard size of bytes, say 1024 bytes, and copy it to the new file. Each time you read the file, your progress is

```
(1024 bytes * NumberOfReads)/SizeOfFileInBytes
```

Comment: sir please give me small example

Comment: Sorry mate, that's your homework. :) Check the links provides as comments by MadProgrammer.