# Progress bar not showing up in copy files from one drive to another program in java

Tags: java, progress-bar, file-copying

I have a program, that copies files from one drive to another written in java. Everything is working fine. I have added a progress bar to indicate the progress on file copying. It does not show up. Below is the codes to copy files. Can't figure out where am I going wrong. The file size is displayed correctly but, the progress bar does not show up.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import java.util.*;

import java.lang.*;

public class CopyGUI1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener, ChangeListener
{
        private JLabel fromLabel, zoneLabel;

        private JTextField fromField, zoneField;

        private JButton beginButton, amd, newSO;

        private String to = "C:\\DCIN_TER\\DCIN_EPU2\\CIRCUIT FROM BRANCH\\Rainbow orders\\";

        private String[] zone = {"SZ","NZ","WZ","EZ","JW","AZ"};

        private JComboBox c;

        private static JProgressBar progressBar;

        int count = 0;

        private long fileLength;

        //Main method

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                new CopyGUI1().setVisible(true);
        }

        public CopyGUI1()
        {
                 init();
        }

        private void init()
        {
                 setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                 setBounds(300, 300, 500, 400);
                 setResizable(false);
                 setTitle("Copy SO from C:\\01_ORDER_PROCESSING\\ drive to C:\\DCIN_TER\\DCIN_EPU2\\ drive");

                 JPanel panel = new JPanel(null);

                 add(panel);

                 //add button and lebel
                 fromLabel = new JLabel("SO No.:");
                 fromLabel.setBounds(40, 20, 50, 20);

                 fromField = new JTextField();
                 fromField.setBounds(100, 20, 200, 20);

                 panel.add(fromLabel);
                 panel.add(fromField);

                 zoneLabel = new JLabel("Zone:");
                 zoneLabel.setBounds(40, 40, 50, 20);

                 zoneField = new JTextField();
                 zoneField.setBounds(140, 40, 200, 20);

                 panel.add(zoneLabel);
                 panel.add(zoneField);

                 c = new JComboBox();

                 for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                         c.addItem(zone[count++]);

                 c.setEditable(false);

                 c.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                        {
                                zoneField.setText("" + c.getSelectedItem());
                         }
                 });

                 c.setBounds(100, 40, 40, 20);

                 panel.add(c);

                 //add progress bar
                 progressBar = new JProgressBar();
                 progressBar.setBounds(50, 100, 300, 30);
                 progressBar.addChangeListener(this);

                 panel.add(progressBar);

                 beginButton = new JButton("Begin Copy");
                 beginButton.setBounds(140, 200, 150, 20);
                 beginButton.addActionListener(this);

                 panel.add(beginButton);

                 amd = new JButton("Copy Amendments");
                 amd.setBounds(140, 220, 150, 20);
                 amd.addActionListener(this);

                 panel.add(amd);

                 newSO = new JButton("Add a new SO");
                 newSO.setBounds(140, 240, 150, 20);
                 newSO.addActionListener(this);

                 panel.add(newSO);
        }

        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
        {
                 if (e.getSource () == beginButton)
                        copy();

                 else if (e.getSource() == amd)
                {
                 CopyAmd c = new CopyAmd();
                        c.show();
                 }

                 else if (e.getSource() == newSO)
                {
                 CopyGUI1 cg = new CopyGUI1();
                        cg.show();
                 }
        }

        public void copy()
        {
                 if(("").equals(fromField.getText()))
                {
                         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Input the SO Number!");

                         return;
                 }

                 if(("").equals(zoneField.getText()))
                {
                         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Input the zone!");

                         return;
                 }

                 Runnable r1 = new Runnable()
                {
                         public void run()
                        {
                                 final File srcFolder = new File("C:\\01_ORDER_PROCESSING\\IN11\\" + zoneField.getText() + "\\" + fromField.getText() + "\\");

                                File destFolder = new File(to + fromField.getText() + "\\");

                                 if(destFolder.exists())
                                {
                                         int op = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, destFolder.getName()+ " file exists! \n Do you want to overwrite it?","Confirm Window", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

                                         if (op == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
                                        {
                                                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Copy Canceled");

                                                 fromField.setText("");
                                                 zoneField.setText("");

                                                 return;
                                         }

                                        else
                                        {
                                                 //make sure source exists
                                                 if(!(srcFolder.exists()))
                                                {
                                                         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Directory does not exist. on " + srcFolder.getAbsolutePath() + " and hence, no files to copy.");

                                                         //just exit
                                                         dispose();
                                         }

                                                else
                                                {
                                                         try
                                                        {
                                                                fileLength = srcFolder.length();
                                                                System.out.println("fileLength : " + fileLength);

                                                                 progressBar.setMaximum((int) fileLength);

                                                                 final long startTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();

                                                         copyFolder(srcFolder, destFolder);

                                                                File file = new File(destFolder + "\\PADR Release\\");

                                                                if(!(file.exists()))
                                                                        file.mkdir();

                                                                final long elapsedTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTimeMillis;

                                                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Copy Task Completed Successfully. The Task took " + elapsedTimeMillis + " milli seconds to complete!!");

                                                                dispose();
                                                         }

                                                        catch(IOException e)
                                                        {
                                                         e.printStackTrace();
                                                         }
                                                }
                                 }
                                }

                                else
                                {
                                        //make sure source exists
                                         if(!(srcFolder.exists()))
                                        {
                                                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Directory does not exist. on " + srcFolder.getAbsolutePath() + " and hence, no files to copy.");

                                                 //just exit
                                                 dispose();
                                 }

                                        else
                                        {
                                                 try
                                                {
                                                        fileLength = srcFolder.length();
                                                        System.out.println("fileLength : " + fileLength);

                                                         progressBar.setMaximum((int) fileLength);

                                                         final long startTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();

                                                 copyFolder(srcFolder, destFolder);

                                                        File file = new File(destFolder + "\\PADR Release\\");

                                                        if(!(file.exists()))
                                                                file.mkdir();

                                                        final long elapsedTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTimeMillis;

                                                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Copy Task Completed Successfully. The Task took " + elapsedTimeMillis + " milli seconds to complete!!");

                                                        dispose();
                                                 }

                                                catch(IOException e)
                                                {
                                                 e.printStackTrace();
                                                 }
                                 }
                                }
                         }
                 };

                 Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);
                 t1.start();
        }

        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
        {
                 if (e.getSource() == progressBar)
                {
                         if (progressBar.getValue() == progressBar.getMaximum())
                        {
                                 //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Copy Over");
                                 progressBar.setValue(0);
                         }
                 }
        }

        public static void copyFolder(File src, File dest) throws IOException
        {
                if(src.isDirectory())
                {
                         //if directory does not exist, create it
                         if(!dest.exists())
                        {
                                   dest.mkdir();
                                System.out.println("Directory copied from " + src + "  to " + dest);
                         }

                         //list all the directory contents
                         String files[] = src.list();

                         for (String file : files)
                        {
                                   //construct the src and dest file structure
                                   File srcFile = new File(src, file);
                                   File destFile = new File(dest, file);

                                //recursive copy
                                   copyFolder(srcFile, destFile);
                         }
                 }

                else
                {
                        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
                   OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest);

                   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                   int length;
                        int flag = 0;

                        while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
                        {
                                     out.write(buffer, 0, length);

                                flag += length;

                                progressBar.setValue(flag);
                           }

                   in.close();
                   out.close();

                   System.out.println("File copied from " + src + " to " + dest);
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer and modified a bit to suit to my needs. Thanks,

Following is the link : [Need to have JProgress bar to measure progress when copying directories and files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574461/need-to-have-jprogress-bar-to-measure-progress-when-copying-directories-and-file)